# Roles en laravel

Tags: laravel, menú, permisos

estoy trabajando con laravel y estoy en la etapa de roles y permisos de mi aplicación.

En mi tabla de users, agregue el un campo llamado rol.

Si rol=1 entonces es administrador

si rol=2 entonces es un usuario normal.

Quisiera que deacuerdo al tipo de rol logueado viera diferentes opciones en el menú.
Espero puedan ayudarme

mi vista del menú es la siguiente:

```
 @if (Auth::guest())
 <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Inicio de sesión</a></li>
 @else
              <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Alumnos <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       <li><a href="{{ url('/alumno') }}">Alumnos inscritos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/alumno2') }}">Grados </a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/alumno3') }}">Materias</a></li>
                        </ul>
                       </li>


  @endif
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pues similar a tu ejemplo solo debes de colocar `if` en los lugares que desees.

Ej:

```
@if (Auth::user()->rol==1)
    Vista para el administrador
@else
    Vista para tu usuario normal 
@endif
```

Así de simple, claro que si tienes muchos mas tipos de usuarios este arruinaría el performace.

Answer (score 0):

Hacer lo que te comenta el otro compañero haría que el rendimiento de tu aplicación sea realmente malo. Solo imagina que tienes 40 módulos de permisos por vista y usuario, seria caótico.
Para ello se usa  [`GATE`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization) o [esta librería](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) que esta muy popularizara y te permite usar en los blade la etiqueta `@can('permiso')`